# How to POST a file using cURL from another domain in php?

Tags: php, post, curl

I was wondering if there any way i can POST some file (that is not on my server)using cURL from a php script I have on my server?

this is example.php

```
$url = 'http://domain.com';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
//Something like this:
$fields = array('file' => 'http://AnotherDomain.com/file.txt');

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
```

I know the correct way would be:

```
$fields = array('file' => '@/var/user/www/file.txt');
```

Thanks you for all your responses.

Comment: Look at the tutorial :http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: I cant find anything related what i wanna do. I need to send a file that is in a 3rd server (Not mine, not target of post request.) some light on this?

Comment: You'll have to download the remote file with `file_get_contents`, temporarily save it, and do the upload.  It cannot read a file to upload from a remote system.  Must be local.